# zsh detect if its tmux window or pane

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'd like to detect if its tmux pane or window. If its window archey should run, if its another pane than not.

I tried following but this obviously won't work.

```
# Only run if archey is actually installed
if which archey &> /dev/null
    then
        if [[ "$ARCHEY_STARTED" != "true" ]]
            then
                export ARCHEY_STARTED=true
                archey
        fi
else
    print "zsh archey plugin: archey not found. Please install archey before using this plugin: brew install archey"
fi
```

am I'm trying to have apple logo only in new windows not panes. You agree in panes it becomes annoying:

[image]

I want to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Programs always run in panes, and a window is just a collection of 1 or more panes. `tmux` commands that take formats have a variable `window_panes` which expands to the number of panes in a window. You might be able to do something with that, only running the command if the count == 1.

Comment: @chepner $TMUX doesn't return anything usable, do you know any env var that returns pane or window info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @chepners suggestion, you can use this as a starting point

```sh
# Only run if archey is actually installed
if which archey &> /dev/null
then
    if [[ "$ARCHEY_STARTED" != "true" -a "1x" == "$(tmux list-panes -F'#{window_panes}' | head -n 1)x" ]]
        then
            export ARCHEY_STARTED=true
            archey
    fi
else
    print "zsh archey plugin: archey not found. Please install archey before using this plugin: brew install archey"
fi
```

I pipe `tmux`s output through `head`, because the command as given will output the pane-count for every pane of the current window.